# Automate tasks using macros in images placed in folders and subfolders using ImageJ

Tags: automation, imagej, imagej-macro

I have recently discovered macros and how they can surprisingly ease my life working on Fiji/ImageJ.

I created this macro:

```
run("Image Sequence...", "open=/home/mario/Desktop/prueba/1/Image-000002.tif");
selectWindow("1");
//setTool("rectangle");
makeRectangle(406, 346, 1132, 845);
run("Z Project...", "projection=[Average Intensity]");
saveAs("Tiff", "/home/mario/Desktop/prueba/1/AVG_1.tif");
```

What this macro does is to import an image sequence stored in the referenced folder, to align the stack of images using the [Template matching plugin](https://sites.google.com/site/qingzongtseng/template-matching-ij-plugin/tuto2), to do focus stacking using the Z Project function (Image > Stacks > Z Project...) and to save the newly generated image in the same folder using the tiff extension.

However, I do have a general folder with plenty subfolders filled with tiff files, so applying one by one the previous macro in each folder could become a tedious task as well. I came across with this [macro](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/macros/BatchProcessFolders.txt) that deals with batch processing:

```
// "BatchProcessFolders"
//
// This macro batch processes all the files in a folder and any
// subfolders in that folder. In this example, it runs the Subtract 
// Background command of TIFF files. For other kinds of processing,
// edit the processFile() function at the end of this macro.
   requires("1.33s"); 
   dir = getDirectory("Choose a Directory ");
   setBatchMode(true);
   count = 0;
   countFiles(dir);
   n = 0;
   processFiles(dir);
   //print(count+" files processed");

   function countFiles(dir) {
      list = getFileList(dir);
      for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
          if (endsWith(list[i], "/"))
              countFiles(""+dir+list[i]);
          else
              count++;
      }
  }

   function processFiles(dir) {
      list = getFileList(dir);
      for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
          if (endsWith(list[i], "/"))
              processFiles(""+dir+list[i]);
          else {
             showProgress(n++, count);
             path = dir+list[i];
             processFile(path);
          }
      }
  }

  function processFile(path) {
       if (endsWith(path, ".tif")) {
           open(path);
           run("Subtract Background...", "rolling=50 white");
           save(path);
           close();
      }
  }
```

However, I do not know how to merge my automated tasks written in my macro with the latter, as I am not an expert in coding.

To sum up, I would like to run my macro in every folder and subfolder automatically from a root directory of my selection.

Can anybody edit and merge the previous macros in order to accomplish my requirements?

Comment: You asked [the same question](http://forum.imagej.net/t/automate-tasks-using-macros-in-images-placed-in-folders-and-subfolders/9468?u=imagejan) on the ImageJ forum and received some answers there. When cross-posting on different locations, please _always_ disclose that you're doing so: you might not be the only one having this issue, and others also want to be able to find the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody came across this question, [the answer can be found in the ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/t/automate-tasks-using-macros-in-images-placed-in-folders-and-subfolders/9468).